# How can set up 'phase' of this complex equation? (Python)

Tags: python, sympy, equation

Here're two equations that I'm trying to solve using sympy.

```
betat, gammat = symbols('betat, gammat')
eq1 = Eq(cos(gammat/2),0.83829184+0.j )
eq2 = Eq(exp(im(i)*betat)*sin(gammat/2),-0.10946281-0.53412048j)
```

However, the current version doesn't quite work since I don't how can I set up the imaginary unit in `exp(im(i)*betat)`. How can I set up the `i` in that equation? Thanks!

Comment: In sympy the imaginary unit is `I` or `sqrt(-1)`.

Comment: @Oscar Benjamin Thanks!!